# Displaying google images on my website?

Tags: php, arrays, image, search, web

so basically I'm trying to display images on my website from google images based on a word stored in an array. Right now, I have this code

```
<?php $lines = file('things.txt');

echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];

?>
```

that just pulls words I have stored in a .txt file, and then randomly displays 1 word from that file (as the $lines array)

What I'm trying to do is then display images from google based on that word that my PHP code randomly grabbed from the .txt file.

Is this do able?
thanks for any help!

Comment: Please start try coding a starting version by yourself, then all users here will be pleased to guide you on how to make it work and improve it.

Comment: Actually I have tried... lots :/ i got it partially working but I didn't think i was doing it correct at all. Perhaps I should make a new post with what I had got so far

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying google images on my website? (revised)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219250/displaying-google-images-on-my-website-revised)

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = fopen('things.txt','r');
$input = fread($file);
$lines = explode("\n",$input);
echo $lines[rand(0,count($lines))];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$lines = file('things.txt', FILE_IGNORE_EMPTY_LINES);
printf('<img src="%s">', trim($lines[array_rand($lines)]));
?>
```

Images from google...? Do you need searching?

Comment: Well right now the website generates and displays a random word each time its refreshed, and I would like to display a bunch of images below the word that are grabbed from google. Just not sure if this is possible ! thanks